# Laravel: trying to make three update functions within one controller

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make three different update functions in CompanyAdressController: defaultUpdate, contactUpdate and generalUpdate.

In first case I'm trying to access them via api:

from my js app:

`this.$http.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/companyDefault/' + this.hospital.default.id, this.hospital.default)`

and inside api routes:

`Route::resource('/companyDefault', 'CompanyAddressController@defaultUpdate');`

and in CompanyAddressController:

```
public function defaultUpdate(Request $request, CompanyAddress $companyAddress)
{
...
}
```

I've got an error:

```
"message": "Method [defaultUpdate@update] does not exist on [App\\Http\\Controllers\\CompanyAddressController].",
    "exception": "BadMethodCallException",
```

How should I correct my routes to get access to my method? Or should I do it different way by making one `controller update` function with parameters from my api function?

Comment: `public function defaultUpdate(Request $request, $companyAddress)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using resourceful controller check laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers. The proper syntax for registering a resourceful controller is:

```
Route::resource('companyDefault', 'CompanyAddressController');
```

I think this is what you want:

```
Route::put('/companyDefault', 'CompanyAddressController@defaultUpdate');
Route::put('/contactUpdate', 'CompanyAddressController@contactUpdate');
Route::put('/generalUpdate', 'CompanyAddressController@generalUpdate');
```

Comment: thanks, it should work, but I've got `405: Method not allowed`, strange

Comment: try using `Route::post`

Comment: also remember to pass csrf token if your using method `post`, `put` or `delete`

Comment: I need to figure it out :)

Comment: what kind JS app are you using? maybe you're using `get` method

Comment: I'm using vue resource, and on this configuration it is working with standard Laravel route resource, but wait, I need more time to try it. I'm not so proficient in api calls  --- yet

Comment: so.. after many checks and fixing my update function: my regular resource `update` works like charm, but when I change only: route to `Route::put('/companyDefault', 'CompanyAddressController@defaultUpdate');` and function name to: `defaultUpdate`, I've got `Response {url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/companyDefault/1", ok: false, status: 405, statusText: "Method Not Allowed",`

Comment: It seems that it is not working, or I don't understand laravel routes

Comment: weird, can you paste your full route file in the question? or maybe your routing is wrong, maybe you want this: `Route::put('/api/companyDefault', 'CompanyAddressController@defaultUpdate');`

Comment: this is not working also. My api routes are nothing special, just auth.jwt and cors middlewares. Tokens are working (because resource route just works under the same middlewares). Okay I'll use just one update function now, with some ifs inside

Comment: maybe try `Route::patch`.. I think

Comment: this gives: `"message": "Method [update] does not exist on [App\\Http\\Controllers\\CompanyAddressController].",
    "exception": "BadMethodCallException",`

Comment: I finally use `Route::post('/companyDefault', 'CompanyAddressController@updateMe');` and this is working. It's strange that `put` doesn't want to work with custom function